# Windows Service Seems not work appropriately

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, windows-services

It is my first time to create a Windows Service and after read many articles on the internet, I made one by myself. It installs successfully, runs, but does not work as expected.

For example:

Inside of a Timer, I call the following code:

```
 Public Sub WriteLog(log As String)
    log = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() & ", " & DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() & vbNewLine & "  -> " & log

    Dim path As String = "c:\Temp\z1111.log"
    Dim sw As StreamWriter

    sw = File.AppendText(path)
    sw.WriteLine(log)
    sw.Flush()
    sw.Close()
End Sub
```

The code above works in a Windows Form project, but as Windows Service it creates a file named z1111.log, add the content overwriting and does not do anything else, but when I delete the file, it creates again with a new date and time.

The question is: why as Windows Form it appends and as Windows Service it overwrites and stop, only works when I delete the file?

It is possible to download the project: [LINK](http://ge.tt/6Ze9iPv/v/0?c)

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: The user which you register the service, is the same of the user that runs the windows form app?

Comment: Hi Diego, it is and the Service I have installed as Local System, with no user and no password.

Comment: Everything, shown here, should work as you expect. Perhaps there is an issue of security or something and you are not getting the error, because it is a service.

Comment: Hi Steve, it is strange because the Service is installed and creates and writes a txt file.

Comment: I changed to write on Windows directory, instead c:\Temp, and it worked as expected. Thanks guys!

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by changing the log file to the Windows folder. It has been a security issue.